# How to pass request into a Laravel Eloquent ::with function?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have this function in my controller:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    return Product::with([
        'producer' => function($producer) {
            dd($request);
            if ( isset($request->producer_id) ) {
                $producer->where(['id','=',$request->producer_id]);
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```

Now the `dd()` said the `$request` is undefined, but if I catch it before `return` it shown correctly.

How can I pass the `$request` variable into the `::with`'s function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, if you want to pass a variable to an inline function, you need to add the `use` identifier together with the required variables. Example:

```
$var = 1.2;

$fn = function ($param1, $param2) use ($var) {
    return ($param1 + $param2) * $var;
};

echo $fn(2, 4); // prints 7.2
```

Answer (score 2):

in order to use `request` you must use the `use` keyword in laravel

```
public function search(Request $request) {
return Product::with([
    'producer' => function($producer) use($request) {
                                      ^^^
        dd($request);
        if ( isset($request->producer_id) ) {
            $producer->where(['id','=',$request->producer_id]);
        }
    }
]);
}
```